# Programmatically check if PIN lock is active in Android

Tags: android, telephony, sim-card, telephonymanager

Here's the thing - I'm doing a security app that needs to be able to check if the PIN code is set or not. The official API returns the same value regardless of the PIN state, and I've been experimenting with ITelephony, but can't seem to get it to work. Any help, please?

Answer (score -1):

Workaround!

```
@override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
  boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
  if (!isScreenOn) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```